# Why is '1' + '1' = 98 and '1' + 1 = 50?

Tags: c++, c++11, ascii

I'm coming from high language, PHP js and things. So this seem strange to me.

I'm using either local or [online](http://cpp.sh/) interpreter but I always get this result.

I suppose this result is because `'2'` is `50` in ASCII and `98` is `'b'` but I'm not sure. Also I don't really understand how the conversion work.

The code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::cout << '1' + 1 << '\n';
    std::cout << '1' + '1' << '\n';
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. what interpreter?

Comment: '1' is 49 in ASCII, so adding one is 50

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, 1 isn't a char. It's an int.
And I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: @ValentinSilvestre: I agree with you on that. This is also about adding an `int` to a constant written as '1'. Plus the types differ in C, so closing to a question also tagged as C doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Because `'1'` is an integer. Don't try learning C++ (or C) from online-tutorial, obscure youtube videos, or trial-by-error. Get as good book.

Comment: @Olaf not in C++ (if you read Bathsheba 's comment)

Comment: @ValentinSilvestre: Yeah, sorry, I corrected (used the `int` out of custom). Still it is an integer.

Comment: On a sidenote: You are most likely using a **compiler**, not an **interpreter**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'1'` is a `char` constant with a specific value determined by the *encoding* used on your system. That encoding might be ASCII, but it might not. When used as an argument to `+`, it is promoted to an `int`. So `decltype('1')` is a `char`, but `decltype('1' + '1')` is an `int`.

On your system, it's clear that `'1'` has the value 49. That's why`'1' + '1'` is 98. And therefore `'1' + 1` is 50.

Note that in C, `'1'` is an `int` type. Arguably that's less confusing than the way C++ has it.

Answer (score 6):

[Type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) `char` is integral type. Each character maps to an integer value. The value depends on the encoding used which in your case is probably [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). So the character `'1'` probably has an integer value of `49` thus the `'1' + '1'` [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) is equivalent to `49 + 49` and results in `98`. Adding integer value of `1` to `49` results in `50`. Which is the same as adding integer value of `1` to (a value represented by the) character `'1'`.

In a nutshell, values are values, whether represented via [character literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) or [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: Yep, integral promotion.

Comment: I was going to go for it :( beat me by a little while.

Comment: I was likely to accept this answer but "probably" sound bad. The answer from @Bathsheba is way more precise and explain better.

Comment: @ValentinSilvestre the "probably" doesn't sound bad at all. It sounds even good, because we cannot be 100% sure that your platform is using ASCII, but it most likely does as other encodings are  rare nowadays.

Comment: Personally I like "probably" as it buries a secret. I also like to bury advanced concepts in my answers. +1,